# ¿Como traer todos los datos de una tabla que no tiene un modelo realacionado en Laravel y que el nombre de la tabla este guardado en una variable?

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

Hola a todos antes que nada muchas gracias por leer mi pregunta, el problema es el siguiente, recibo el nombre de la tabla que quiero consultar a traves de un resquest, esto con el objetivo de consultar tablas dinamicamente estas tablas existen en mi base de datos pero no estan relacionadas o tienen un modelo.
Les muestro la función de mi controlador donde intento llevar acabo esto:

```
  public function getTable($data)
    {
        try {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM' . ' ' . $data;
            $rows = DB::select($sql);

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'rows' =>$rows,
            ]);
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Estoy intentando de es manera pero no logro tener exito esto no me retorna nada.
Desde ya agradezco sus respuestas u opinines para resolver mi problema.

Comment: en principio deberia de funcionar, por que es un string, y le estas concatenando $data, lo que no estoy seguro es en el select, prueba utilizando \DB::table($sql)->get();, ademas imprime el valor de data para ver si lleva algun valor

Comment: Al margen de la pregunta no te recomiendo ejecutar la consulta de esa manera ya que te estás exponiendo a sql inyection al concatenar la query sin filtrarla antes. Además, responder con el mensaje de error en el ````catch```` puede generar una brecha de seguridad importante, un equivalente a tener el modo debug habilitado en un ambiente de producción. Puedes utilizar la fachada ````DB```` o en su defecto replantearte si realmente necesitas prescindir de un modelo.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @SoyCésarMora, lo tomare en cuenta y replanteare el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La manera correcta de buscar las tablas que no estan relacionadas en Laravel o al menos la que a mi me funciono es de la siguiente manera:

```
 public function getRows($data)
    {
        try {
            
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM' . ' ' . $data;
            $rows = DB::select($sql);
            
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'rows' => $rows
            ]);
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que DB::select() es para pedir columnas especificas como el ejemplo de [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#specifying-a-select-clause).

para traer la tabla como tu quieres puedes hacer esto.

```
public function getTable($data)
{
    try {
    //$data debe contener el nombre de la tabla 
        $dinamicTable = DB::table($data)->get();

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'rows' => $dinamicTable,
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
```